# Multiple rows in table with values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, multiplication

I am struggling with following issue:

Table1:

[image]

Table2:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Basically I want to multiple rows in dates table with rows from User table. Is it somehow possible? (using TSQL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply cross join

```
select date,month,userid,userno from table1 cross join table2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Date, Month, USER_ID, ID from
t1 cross join t2
```